# Bootstrap 4 mr-auto alignment not working in navbar?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have looked through other similar questions on this site yet could not interpret an answer for myself as I am a beginner regarding web development. I want to have the contact link in my navbar be aligned to the right of the navbar. However, mr-auto and everything else I have tried has not worked. mr-auto just makes it look like a hyperlink without moving it to the right hand side at all. The following is my html code and the css stylesheet is currently empty so I have nothing to show for that.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <!-- Left Corner Title -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Portfolio v1 </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <!-- Nav Bar List -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Projects </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> About Me </a>
            </li>
            
            <!-- Right Corner -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link float-right" href="#"> Contact </a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>

          <!----
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        -->

        </div>
      </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want entire menu rightside or contact only

Answer (score 3):

`mr-auto` adds an auto margin on the right side, thus pushing everything to the left. If you want to push everything on the right, you need to have `ml-auto`. Just replace that, and all your links will be aligned to the right (valid till BootStrap 4).

For any BootStrap 5 users, `mr` becomes `me` & `ml` becomes `ms`.

Comment: I just realized the version. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 4, the **mr-auto** class puts an auto margin on the **right** side so the elements will move towards the left as there will be a margin on their right.
You have to use the **ml-auto** class on the Contact link so that it has a margin on its **left** side and so it will move towards the right. Also, take the contact link out of the `<ul>` for the ml-auto class to take effect.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <!-- Left Corner Title -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Portfolio v1 </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <!-- Nav Bar List -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Projects </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> About Me </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Corner -->
            <!-- <li class="nav-item"> -->
            <a class="nav-link ml-auto" href="#"> Contact </a>
            <!-- </li> -->

        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify its position from right using the `position` property in CSS. But keep in mind when elements will collapse in the menu in navbar then it might look ugly. In that case use `@media` query to correct the position. Set proper id of li element containing *contact* and also place the link of your stylesheet below that of Bootstrap .

```css
#rt{
  position:absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

If you feel confused by all this then please read about [position](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26/) and [@media](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-principles/create-a-media-query) .

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

1. **ml-auto** - Right align
2. **mx-auto** - Center align
3. **mr-auto** - Left align

use the above class as per your requirement. :)